# trying to export both columns and rows to excel for a query like , select * from customer where customer_id=2323234

Tags: python

I'm trying to print both columns and rows for select query-ex:

```
select * from customer where customer_id=2323234


for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(r, c, col)
```

the above logic is writing only row but not column or headers into excel

to export both rows and columns to excel from python.
My DB is Oracle.

Comment: What does "writing only row but not column" mean?

Comment: like sql query shows  both column names and actual data, i want to export both to excel